# Not able to make an array of Classes in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

So I am trying to create an array that consist of multiple classes that I call `Homes`

But when I run my code, my array consist only of one `Home`
I am doing this in Rails framework.

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController

    def index
        home_names_array = ['Kodu 1' 'Kodu 2']
        homes = []

        home_names_array.each do |home|
            x = Homes.new
            x.home_name = home
            x.create_apartments(['Korter 56', 'Korter 78'])
            homes << x
        end

        homes.each do |x|
            logger.debug homes.size
            logger.debug "Home name: #{x.get_name}\n"
        end
    end

    class Home
        attr_accessor :home_name
        APARTMENTS = []

        def create_apartments(apartment_names)
            apartment_names.each do |apartment|
                x = Apartment.new
                x.apartment_name = apartment
                APARTMENTS << x
            end
        end

        def get_name
            home_name
        end

        def get_apartments
            APARTMENTS.each do |apartment|
                apartment
            end
        end
    end

    class Apartment
        attr_accessor :apartment_name

        def get_apartment_name
            apartment_name
        end
    end

end
```

In the index action, it should push the x which is a class to my array. But the outcome is just a variable with one Class in it.

Comment: did you try to debug the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing comma in your `home_names_array`. It should be `home_names_array = ['Kodu 1', 'Kodu 2']`

Comment: 1 hour trying to find the problem and in the end the problem is a comma...   Thank you for pointing out the error!